# Convert data into matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the data which is stored as data1.txt, which looks something like this

```
1,004,-59
1,004,-65
1,004,-69
1,005,-55
1,005,-57
1,006,-53
1,006,-59
1,007,-65
1,007,-69
1,007,-55
1,007,-57
1,008,-53
1,009,-59
1,009,-65
1,009,-69
1,009,-55
1,010,-57
1,010,-53
1,010,-59
1,010,-65
1,011,-69
1,011,-55
1,011,-57
1,011,-53
```

Running a python code to seperate data into lines and then seperate it individually.

```
with open('data1.txt') as test:
    try:  
        test = open('data1.txt')
        line = test.readline()
        cnt = 1

        while line:
           print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
           data = line.split(',')
           line = test.readline()
           cnt += 1
           print(data[0],data[1],data[2])
    finally:  
        test.close()
```

But want to showcase it as n*3 matrix each time the value of column 1 and column 2 match.How shall I proceed from here using numpy.matrix??

Desired output:

```
Line 1: 1,004,-59
Line 2: 1,004,-65
Line 3: 1,004,-69
[[1,004,-59],[1,004,-65],[1,004,-69]]
Line 4: 1,005,-55
Line 5: 1,005,-57
[[1,005,-55],[1,005,-57]]
.
.
.
.
```

and so on.

Comment: Look at `numpy.loadtxt()`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: what you mean by matching column 1 and 2 ?

Comment: 1,004,-59
1,004,-65
1,004,-69 here column 1 and column 2 value matches i meant by that.

Comment: Considering the input that you show, can you also show the output that you expect?

Comment: Line 1: 1,004,-59
1 004 -59

Line 2: 1,004,-65
1 004 -65

Line 3: 1,004,-69
1 004 -69

Line 4: 1,005,-55
1 005 -55

Line 5: 1,005,-57
1 005 -57

Comment: something like this

Comment: @ShubhamKuse (1) please add the desired output to the question, don't post it as comment. (2) How is the matching of the first two columns taken into account in your example output?

Comment: i have edited the question,hope i have answered both the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a solution where I first collect all the values in a dictionary. In the solution below I assume that the order in which the values appear in the file is important. If not, you can replace the `OrderedDict` with a normal `dict`. Note also that in Python version 3.7 the usual `dict` is ordered.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

input_dict = OrderedDict()

with open('data1.txt') as test:
    for line in test:
        data = list(map(int,line.split(',')))
        key = (data[0],data[1])
        input_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(data)

for key,val in input_dict.items():
    print('{} : {}'.format(key, val))
```

gives the output

```
(1, 4) : [[1, 4, -59], [1, 4, -65], [1, 4, -69]]
(1, 5) : [[1, 5, -55], [1, 5, -57]]
(1, 6) : [[1, 6, -53], [1, 6, -59]]
(1, 7) : [[1, 7, -65], [1, 7, -69], [1, 7, -55], [1, 7, -57]]
(1, 8) : [[1, 8, -53]]
(1, 9) : [[1, 9, -59], [1, 9, -65], [1, 9, -69], [1, 9, -55]]
(1, 10) : [[1, 10, -57], [1, 10, -53], [1, 10, -59], [1, 10, -65]]
(1, 11) : [[1, 11, -69], [1, 11, -55], [1, 11, -57], [1, 11, -53]]
```

Note that these are lists (what you apparently want, judging from your output). If you want arrays, use numpy and add

```
for key, val in input_dict.items():
    input_dict[key] = np.array(val)
```

before you print out your values. Hope this helps.

Comment: this helps a bit but at the output shows something like this 
 [  1  11 -55]
 [  1  11 -57]
 [  1  11 -53]]

Comment: it seems to take the final value of the key.will look through the errors and let you know in this thread.

Comment: @ShubhamKuse I don't understand, what is the problem?

Comment: it only takes the final value of the given val and key parameters instead of the above output.

Comment: @ShubhamKuse It doesn't for me. Are you running exactly the code I posted? What version of python are you using?

Comment: 3.6.yes i am running the exact code with the added array part at the bottom